# Equivariant Cohomology of homotopy equivalent spaces

Tags: homology-cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

Let $V$ is contractible space with $T$ torus action, then can I say their equivariant cohomology (in Borel sense) are equal ? i.e for  $\bullet = point$ ,  $H_T^*(V)=H_T^*(\bullet)$ ?

Comment: You need that they are contractible through equivariant maps as equivariant cohomology is functorial with respect to equivariant maps. I don't immediately see a counterexample of a  contractible space with an $S^1$ action that is not contractible through an equivariant homotopy.

Answer (score 1):

Equivariant cohomology are defined as ordinary cohomology of $V \times_G EG$. There is a projection $p: V \times_G EG \rightarrow BG$.This projection is fiber bundle with fiber $V$.

If $V$ is contractible, then this projection is homotopy equivalence, hence induces isomorphism on cohomology $H^{*} (BG) \rightarrow H^{*} ( V \times_G EG)$. I.e. isomorphism $H^*_G ( \bullet ) \rightarrow H^*_G(V)$